# Create directory inside stored procedure plsql

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql, directory

I have this code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_dir(id number, filename varchar2, dir varchar2)
IS  
  sqlQ varchar2;
BEGIN   
   sqlQ := 'create directory DIR0001 as '||dir;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sqlQ);
END;
```

I am trying to create a directory inside stored procedure and pass the value by parameter but i get the error:

```
   Package or function INSERT_DIR is in an invalid state
06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
           invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
           detected errors.
*Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function for syntax
           errors or incorrectly assigned, or missing, privileges for a
           referenced object.
```

call  procedure:

```
CALL insert_dir(3,'pic.jpg','C:\Users\User\Desktop\media');
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compiling the procedure, it should have said "Procedure created with compilation errors."

If you issue `SHOW ERRORS` it would have told you the compilation error and which line.

In this case, the error is on this line - the declaration requires a size for the VARCHAR2, e.g.:

```
sqlQ varchar2(4000);
```